# Not getting the desired Output.Scanner not working properly. Help me

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I run the following code it takes the name as input, also the code but then then it bypass the address and the program stops! What is the Problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class demo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String address;
        int code;
        System.out.println("Enter Your NAME : ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Your CODE : ");
        code = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your ADDRESS : ");
        address = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `input.nextLine();` after `code = input.nextInt();` to accept the carriage return character left behind by the `nextInt()`

Comment: but can you tell me why is this happening?

Comment: @Spider - When you use `nextInt()`, if you enter  say `5` and hit Enter, the carriage return character will be still in the stream. Only the number will be read. The `nextLine()` will read it and thus you will think that address has been skipped. So, add a `input.nextLine()` after call to `nextInt()' to gobble up that character.